# Ionic2 and Angular2 image upload example?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**This code is not working..**

```js
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input ngControl="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Category Name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Image</ion-label>
    <ion-input ngControl="image" type="file" placeholder="Select Category Image"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Is there any way to upload image file using Ion-input and get uploaded file in type script using formBuilder.?

```js
formBuilder.group({
  name:  ['', Validators.required],
  image: ['', Validators.required]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

To upload image to the server using Ionic 2 Framework, you have to use the Transfer plugin.
Install transfer plugin using

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install --save @ionic-native/transfer
```

Then call the upload function from Transfer class.

```
const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
     fileKey: 'file',
     fileName: 'name.jpg',
     headers: {}

  }

 fileTransfer.upload(imageDataLocalURL, 'http://localhost/ionic/upload.php',  options1)
.then((data) => {
 // success
 alert("success");
}, (err) => {
 // error
 alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Use the link to know more https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-version-2/upload-an-image-to-the-php-server-using-ionic-2-transfer-and-camera-plugin

Comment: Can i use multiple images to upload at one hit?

Comment: I still didn't get solution of this